# Does copying files from NTFS to EXT4 degrade/corrupt the files?

Tags: hard-drive, ntfs, ext4

The reason I ask is I am very new to Ubuntu, but I want to get into mobile development. I installed Ubuntu alongside windows 8 but it just doesn't run quite as well as I would expect so a friend mentioned that Ubuntu would run smoother if you started with a completely blank disk, no windows.

So I want to do this and ditch windows since I can see Ubuntu easily allows me to complete my basic tasks (goodbye Skyrim :tears:). but I do want to keep all my music, videos and documents from windows.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its a nice thought, but no it doesn't. You will just need to set the permissions for all the files since NTFS doesn't support that.

However, you should think about having a dual boot, if it is that you installed Ubuntu alongside Windows with Wubi. If you do have a dual boot, there is no real reason why Ubuntu should be slow, except if you have your Ubuntu partition full, or have allocated no swap partition.

Comment: Currently i have windows 8 on my 120gb SSD and ubuntu on a 1TB EXT4 partition of a 2TB 7200rpm drive. I have 8 gigs of ram and 16 gigs of swap partitioned. (i read somewhere you need 2x ram for swap). I have my graphics drivers installed, using radeon hd 7770. I wouldnt say the OS is slow as much as i experience some graphical glitches and poor game performance playing games that should run perfect on my rig.

Comment: So it seems Ubuntu has more than plenty of space, assuming its not full. Your problem must be related to the graphics drivers available for your graphics card, I have always heard ATI doesn't play very well with Linux; you should read on questions related to ATI cards and performance.

Comment: Also, you have an excess of swap space, the 2·RAM "rule" was sensible when systems came with little RAM, now you should be more than fine with 8 GB of swap.

Comment: Thanks for your responses @WolterHellmund i'll do some research into that. What tends to play nice then, nvidia or amd?

Comment: From what I've heard, nVidia. They have been providing proprietary drivers which work very nicely; on top of that, there are open source drivers that work ok but most won't be as good in 3D acceleration as the proprietary drivers. I don't know about AMD.